# getting hyperlinks with a certain prefix on python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, href

I was trying to create a function to get a link to another Wikipedia page from one. Link to All other wiki articles starts with the prefix "/wiki/". I tried a code to get one random link but my code was getting all the class. After that, I saw the following code on the internet.

```
allLinks = soup.find(id="bodyContent").find_all("a")
    random.shuffle(allLinks)
    linkToScrape = 0

    for link in allLinks:
        # We are only interested in other wiki articles
        if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:
            continue

        # Use this link to scrape
        linkToScrape = link
        break
```

This code chunk seems to work perfectly. However, I couldn't understand a part.

```
if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:
```

I couldn't understand the use of -1. Moreover, can someone explain how the conditional in this line of code works and how the `find` function is used here?
For background, here is the page I found the code on: "https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/scraping-wikipedia-articles-with-python/"

Comment: You want all other `/wiki/` links or non `wiki` links?

Comment: all wiki links.

Comment: What do you expect is us do? I didn't understand your question properly!

Answer (score 2):

`s.find(sub)` returns `-1` if the substring `sub` is not found in the string `s`.  So in this case it is saying "If we don't find /wiki/ in the link string then continue because it is not a wikipedia link".

The reason why it is a weird number like `-1` is because `find` returns the index the substring is found at and that could be any positive number or `0`.  So `-1` is used to signify *not found at any index*.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Although it seems like `startswith` would be more appropriate in this case:

```
if not link['href'].starts("/wiki/"):
    continue
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Comment: `links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select("#bodyContent [href^='/wiki/']")]`  - better yet, only gather qualifying links from the start, then get rid of all that unnecessary code.

Comment: Yes @QHarr that would be a better overall solution, I realize their question is sort of 2-fold: 1. How do I find these links? 2. What is this line in this example doing?